# TomEE startup error: Cannot create unique file, please set java.io.tmpdir to a writable folder or create work folder

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-tomee, openejb, homebrew-cask

While starting up my application from within IntelliJ 14 the app server TomEE 7.0.62 gives following error message:

```
cannot create unique file, please set java.io.tmpdir to a writable folder or create work folder
at org.apache.openejb.assembler.DeployerEjb.<clinit>(DeployerEjb.java:109)
```

System:
OSX, IntelliJ 14, TomEE-Plume 7.0.62 (homebrew), Java 8 (homebrew cask)

Java version:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
1.8.0_60, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Deployment: The basic Hello World sample app from Vaadin Framework 7

Infos:

- TomEE startup over Terminal with startup.sh works ok, default tomcat welcome screen is shown on localhost:8080
- Tried to add JVM option to set java.io.tmpdir to a different directory with chmod 777 privileges. `VM options: -Djava.io.tmpdir=<new temp dir>`
- Tried to export env variable with `export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.io.tmpdir=<new temp dir>`
- With Tomcat 8 hello world app works ok

Full error log:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.openejb.util.Classes.forName(Classes.java:64)
at org.apache.openejb.config.rules.ValidationBase.loadClass(ValidationBase.java:151)
at org.apache.openejb.config.rules.CheckMethods.check_unusedCreateMethods(CheckMethods.java:318)
at org.apache.openejb.config.rules.CheckMethods.validate(CheckMethods.java:55)
at org.apache.openejb.config.rules.ValidationBase.validate(ValidationBase.java:50)
at org.apache.openejb.config.AppValidator.validate(AppValidator.java:101)
at org.apache.openejb.config.ValidateModules.deploy(ValidateModules.java:38)
at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory$Chain.deploy(ConfigurationFactory.java:403)
at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:971)
at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.getOpenEjbConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:526)
at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.getOpenEjbConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:591)
at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.getOpenEjbConfiguration(Assembler.java:459)
at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.build(Assembler.java:438)
at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init>(OpenEJB.java:150)
at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB.init(OpenEJB.java:298)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatLoader.initialize(TomcatLoader.java:256)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener.install(ServerListener.java:168)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener.lifecycleEvent(ServerListener.java:55)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)

Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: cannot create     unique file, please set java.io.tmpdir to a writable folder or create work folder
at org.apache.openejb.assembler.DeployerEjb.<clinit>(DeployerEjb.java:109)
... 32 more
```

Thank you all..

Comment: Tried your setup on MacOS - no problems, started like expected. What Java are you using? Oracle JRE or JDK? Some other vendor?

Comment: Added the infos.. Regular Java SE 8 from homebrew cask ('brew cask install java'). I'm using the TomEE-Plume edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add openejb.system.apps=false in conf/system.properties or just export CATALINA_TMPDIR to a "new tmp dir value"

Comment: Suggestion with CATALINA_TMPDIR did indeed solve the problem.

Used `catalina.sh version` in TomEE/bin to find out where does CATALINA_TMPDIR direct to. Then altered the permissions of this directory. Works fine!

Setting CATALINA_TMPDIR as an environment variable within IntelliJ 14 with Build Configuration -> Defaults -> Application -> Environment variables didn't work. The same error kept coming up. (Haven't tried Terminal with 'export...')

Thanks for your help rmannibucau!